# How do I efficiently generate Prime Numbers up until 3037000499 (the square root of Long.MAX)?

Tags: java, primes, long-integer

I tried it with Sieve Of Eratosthenes, but I quickly run into the problem that my boolean array can't go past Integer.MAX

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: You could try using a BitSet, which should take about an eighth the memory of a boolean array.

Comment: BitSet is the answer. You could implement one yourself, but why bother?

Comment: You only need to sieve odd numbers since 2 is the only even prime.  That will halve the storage requirement for your BitSet.  If that doesn't work, use a segmented sieve, dealing with the whole range in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Arrays

Use 2 or more dimensional maps. So converting long to two integers (for accessing the arrays) will be like this:

`array[N / Integer.MAX_VALUE][N % Integer.MAX_VALUE]` where N is `long` and `array` is the boolean array.

Comment: Internally HashMap is backed by an array, which means it cannot contain more than `Integer.MAX` items.

Comment: You are right, I will remove that. Thank you for pointing it out.